# How to deploy a Java command line application?

Tags: java, deployment

I started to write code in Java few weeks ago. I use IntelliJ Idea (the latest version) on Win10x64.

I realized a little hangman game (as a Windows command line app) that uses a text file with the words and I have put this text file in a folder called 'assets' inside the project folder (at the same level of 'src' folder). The game works great in the IDE environment but I still don't know how to realize a standalone app and running it outside IntelliJ.

I tried also to compile from command line using javac.exe and it seems that compilation works well but when I try to execute the program from command line using java.exe I get an error that says that the text file I use as vocabulary is not found (`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`).

I have also followed the instructions on Jet Brains site about [How to create a JAR file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#package)  but with no results. Is there a simple way to deploy a Java desktop application so that people (who obviously have JRE) have just to make a double click on an icon and use it?

Comment: Maven can build an executable JAR with very little configuration https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: Please show the code you use to get the text file.

Comment: This is really two separate questions. One question is about how to successfully read your text file when running the application outside of the IDE. The second question is how to bundle up your app in a way that people can easily launch it. I would focus on the first question (getting your app to work outside the IDE) before you worry about the details of the second question.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: *"command line application"* By the way. Unless the app. is run from the command prompt, there will be no way for the user to add input or see output. So a 'double click to run' executable Jar is not an option for this.